# Yii2 multilingual slug and language switcher that will "respect" translated slug's

Tags: yii2, internationalization, slug, language-switching

The problem is - I can't figure out how to switch to translated slug:

I've implemented multilingual slugs using `lav45/yii2-translated-behavior`.

Database is quite simple:

**Portfolio model:**

`id | created_at | is_active`

**PortfolioLang model:**

`portfolio_id | lang_id | title | content`

So far - so good. I have a `actionView` that calls out translated content as follows:

```
    protected function findModelBySlug($slug)
    {
        if (($model = Portfolio::findOne(['slug' => $slug])) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }
    }

    public function actionView($_lang, $slug)
    {
        $portfolioLang = PortfolioLang::findOne(['lang_id' => $_lang,'slug' => $slug]);

        $model = $portfolioLang->portfolio;
        
        $pictures = PortfolioPicture::find()->where(['portfolio_id' => $model->id])->orderBy(['sorting'=>SORT_ASC])->all();       

        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $model,
            'picture' => $pictures,
            'langList' => Lang::getList(),
        ]);
    }
```

Must note, that this is working, "until" it try to switch between languages while I'm opened the entry.

I was using example code from here: https://github.com/lav45/yii2-translated-behavior-demo/blob/master/frontend/components/LangHelper.php

I guess that I need something else than a sample code (it looks like it works only for current ID's for existing entries). Could you, someone, give me some hints for the next step?

Thanks in advance!